# Exibir variavel JS no HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Fala pessoal, tenho uma variável js que conta o numero de pontos baseado em um questionário, ela conta os pontos corretamente, só não sei como posso exibir esse valor da variável no meu html, alguém pode ajudar por favor?

Aqui esta meu js

```
function contarPontos() {
    if (!localStorage.pontos) {
        localStorage.pontos = 0;
    }
    localStorage.pontos = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("pontos")) + 10;
}
```

E aqui meu HTML onde quero exibir

```
                    <div class="mu-title">
                        <span class="style-texto-conclusao">Sua pontuação foi pontos!</span>
                        <div id="contarPontos"></div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso basta usar o `innerHTML` para mostrar a pontuação. Basta recuperar a pontuação e atribuir ela ao elemento com o `id=contarPontos`.

```
function contarPontos() {
    if (!localStorage.pontos) {
        localStorage.pontos = 0;
    }
    localStorage.pontos = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("pontos")) + 10;
    document.getElementById("contarPontos").innerHTML = localStorage.pontos;
}
```

Caso esteja usando `jQuery`, pode fazer dessa forma

```
$("#contarPontos").text(localStorage.pontos)
```